# Add spellcheck to non-contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to run the browser's in built spell checker on divs which aren't contenteditable? The below code works for checking spelling, but the div must be contenteditable and the spell check is only executed once the div is put into focus.

```
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true">
    This paragraph gets spell checked when the div comes into focus
</div>
```

I want to display a full page of html and have the red squiggly lines underneath all the mis spelled words

Comment: Spellcheck works only on the areas where editing is possible.

Comment: Make some search... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_spellcheck.asp

Comment: I know the intended functionality, but are there are no workarounds or plugins that have been made?

Comment: @alsco77 I doubt it.

Comment: Checked everywhere mate. Not possible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar What about setting all of the content in content editable elements, then using jQuery to loop through them, set in focus (to get errors underlined) then go through and remove the content editable tags?

Comment: @alsco77 Simple way is, have tabindex set, and once on focus, make jQuery to make it contenteditable. Let me answer it and see if that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code to apply the spell checker using jquery-2.2.1.js. I made all divs contenteditable and then after view loaded ran:

```
$('.content-container').each((i, el: any) => {
    $(el)[0].focus();
    $(el)[0].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');            
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me say, these steps might work:

- Make all the `<div>` to be focussable by adding a `tabindex` attribute.
- Once focussed, using jQuery (as it is not possible using CSS), add `contenteditable` attribute.
- Once blurred, remove the `contenteditable` attribute.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".ce").focus(function () {
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", true);
  }).blur(function () {
    $(this).prop("contenteditable", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Click here and press tab!" />
<div class="ce" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis dolorem consequatur doloribus at, quam ipsam repudiandae libero ullam, commodi cum hic nam odit reiciendis? Distinctio inventore quasi, ex cupiditate neque.</div>
<div class="ce" tabindex="0">Sunt, consequatur. Dolorem odio nihil minima, in autem corrupti. Animi atque, eius laudantium. Excepturi laudantium suscipit esse nulla tempore aspernatur architecto. Dolorem a impedit, dolor voluptatum repellat mollitia itaque quod.</div>
<div class="ce" tabindex="0">Aliquam dolores, ipsam vel eum sed necessitatibus itaque error doloribus illum, omnis, ex exercitationem commodi neque quos voluptatibus debitis rem amet praesentium! Quibusdam corporis mollitia modi? In dignissimos ad itaque.</div>
<div class="ce" tabindex="0">Maxime, totam laudantium accusantium itaque sint possimus ex minus deleniti adipisci reprehenderit commodi illo corporis provident sed tempore architecto molestiae! Molestiae voluptas magni, non, ex assumenda quibusdam aliquam vitae ab.</div>
<div class="ce" tabindex="0">Quibusdam magnam, maiores eveniet commodi consequuntur sapiente, deleniti praesentium eius blanditiis. Suscipit fugit in repellendus quis ducimus illum, tempore voluptatem incidunt recusandae a perferendis id, distinctio vitae voluptatibus quibusdam necessitatibus.</div>
```